# Anular ítem con descuento en Hasar SMH/PT-1000F

Tags: windows

Me encuentro programando la fiscal **Hasar SMH/PT-1000F** utilizando la DLL provista por la empresa y me encontré con un problema. No puedo anular un ítem vendido que posee descuento.

Para agregar un descuento utilizo el comando **ImprimirDescuentoItem** el cúal lo hace sobre el último ítem vendido. Esto funciona correctamente.

El problema se presenta al querer anular el ítem que posee el descuento. Primeramente la función **ImprimirItem** que utilizo para agregar el ítem no retorna el parametro **IndiceAuditoria** (El manual dice que no lo soporta este modelo de impresora), entonces no puedo utilizar el comando **AnularItem**.

Para resolver la anulación intenté las siguientes opciones:

- Utilizar el comando **ImprimirItem** con el valor del descuento aplicado para anularlo y luego envíar el mismo comando con los datos del ítem original pero en modo resta.
- Utilizar el comando **AnularItem** con el número de movimiento envíado a la impresora (si el ítem a anular fue el 5, se envía ese número). La mpresora reporta que no existe un ítem con ese *índice de auditoría*
- No ejecutar el comando **ImprimirDescuentoItem** y Utilizar al final el comando **ImprimirAjuste**. funciona siempre y cuando todos los ítems regados sean de la misma alicuota de IVA, lo cúal la mayoría de las veces no es así en la práctica.
- En lugar de utilizar el comando **ImprimirDescuentoItem**, agregar el descuento como un ítem más y en negativo. La impresora deja realizar esta acción porque anteriormente no se agrego el mismo ítem con mayor o igual valor al monto a descontar.

Envíe un correo a la gente de **Hasar**. Todavía no han contestado pero lo mandé ayer y tal véz todavía ni lo leyeron.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hablando con la gente de Hasar por correo se plantearon dos soluciones:

**Solución 1** Vender el mismo ítem en negativo con el descuento calculado por software.

1. Se debe utilizar el comando **ImprimirItem** para agregar el ítem vendido.
2. Se debe utilizar el comando **ImprimirDescuentoItem** para agregar el descuento.
3. Se debe calcular la diferencia entre el total del ítem agregado en 1 y el descuento aplicado en 2.
4. Se debe utilizar el comando **ImprimirItem** en modo resta con el importe calculado en 3.

El paso 3 y 4 son los que se utilizan al momento de anular el ítem.

Ejemplo:

```
//Paso 1
hasar.
ImprimirItem(
  "Producto Uno ...",
  1.0,
  171.61,
  HasarArgentina.CondicionesIVA.Gravado,
  21.0,
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeMonto.ModoSumaMonto, 
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeImpuestosInternos.IIVariablePorcentual,
  10.0,
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeDisplay.DisplayNo,
  HasarArgentina.ModosDePrecio.ModoPrecioTotal,
  1,
  "7791234500001",
  "00001",
  HasarArgentina.UnidadesMedida.Unidad)

//Paso 2
hasar.
ImprimirDescuentoItem(
  "Oferta Uno ...",
  15.85,
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeDisplay.DisplayNo,
  HasarArgentina.ModosDePrecio.ModoPrecioTotal)

//Paso 3
//Se calcula la diferencia para el paso 4

//Paso 4
hasar.
ImprimirItem(
  "Producto Uno ...", 
  1.0,
  155.76,
  HasarArgentina.CondicionesIVA.Gravado,
  21.0,
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeMonto.ModoRestaMonto,
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeImpuestosInternos.IIVariablePorcentual,
  10.0,
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeDisplay.DisplayNo,
  HasarArgentina.ModosDePrecio.ModoPrecioTotal,
  1,
  "7791234500001",
  "00001",
  HasarArgentina.UnidadesMedida.Unidad)
```

**Solución 2** Utilizar el comando *ImprimirItem* para agregar y quitar el descuento.

1. Se debe utilizar el comando **ImprimirItem** para agregar el ítem vendido. El parametro **CódigoArticulo** se debe establecer y el parametro **CódigoInterno** no.
2. Se debe utilizar el comando **ImprimirItem** en modo resta para agregar el descuento. Los parametros **Descripcion** y **CodigoArticulo** deben tener el mismo valor que los utilizados en el paso 1 y el parametro **CodigoInterno** no se debe establecer.
3. Se debe utilizar el comando **ImprimirItem** en modo suma para contrarestar el ítem agregado en el paso 2. Los parametros **Descripcion** y **CodigoArticulo** deben tener el mismo valor que los utilizado en el paso 2 y el parametro **CodigoInterno** no se debe establecer.
4. Se debe utilizar el comando **ImprimirItem** en modo resta para contrarestar el ítem agregado en el paso 1. Los parametros **Descripcion** y **CodigoArticulo** deben tener el mismo valor que los utilizado en el paso 1 y el parametro **CodigoInterno** no se debe establecer.

Los pasos 3 y 4 corresponden a la anulación del ítem.

Ejemplo:

```
//Paso 1
hasar.
ImprimirItem(
  "Producto Uno ...",//Descripcion
  171.61,//Cantidad
  ld_precio_unitario,//PrecioUnitario
  HasarArgentina.CondicionesIVA.Gravado,//CondicionIVA
  21,//AlicuotaIVA
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeMonto.ModoSumaMonto,//OperacionMonto
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeImpuestosInternos.IIVariablePorcentual,//TipoImpuestoInterno
  10.0,//MagnitudImpuestoInterno
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeDisplay.DisplayNo,//ModoDisplay
  HasarArgentina.ModosDePrecio.ModoPrecioTotal,//ModoBaseTotal
  1,//UnidadReferencia
  "7791234500001",//CodigoProducto
  "",//CodigoInterno
  HasarArgentina.UnidadesMedida.Unidad//
)

//Paso 2
hasar.
ImprimirItem(
  "Producto Uno ...",//Descripcion
  20.31,//Cantidad
  ld_precio_unitario,//PrecioUnitario
  HasarArgentina.CondicionesIVA.Gravado,//CondicionIVA
  21,//AlicuotaIVA
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeMonto.ModoRestaMonto,//OperacionMonto
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeImpuestosInternos.IIVariablePorcentual,//TipoImpuestoInterno
  10.0,//MagnitudImpuestoInterno
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeDisplay.DisplayNo,//ModoDisplay
  HasarArgentina.ModosDePrecio.ModoPrecioTotal,//ModoBaseTotal
  1,//UnidadReferencia
  "7791234500001",//CodigoProducto
  "",//CodigoInterno
  HasarArgentina.UnidadesMedida.Unidad//
)

//Paso 3 - Se decide anular el ítem
hasar.
ImprimirItem(
  "Producto Uno ...",//Descripcion
  20.31,//Cantidad
  ld_precio_unitario,//PrecioUnitario
  HasarArgentina.CondicionesIVA.Gravado,//CondicionIVA
  21,//AlicuotaIVA
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeMonto.ModoSumaMonto,//OperacionMonto
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeImpuestosInternos.IIVariablePorcentual,//TipoImpuestoInterno
  10.0,//MagnitudImpuestoInterno
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeDisplay.DisplayNo,//ModoDisplay
  HasarArgentina.ModosDePrecio.ModoPrecioTotal,//ModoBaseTotal
  1,//UnidadReferencia
  "7791234500001",//CodigoProducto
  "",//CodigoInterno
  HasarArgentina.UnidadesMedida.Unidad//
)

//Paso 4
hasar.
ImprimirItem(
  "Producto Uno ...",//Descripcion
  171.61,//Cantidad
  ld_precio_unitario,//PrecioUnitario
  HasarArgentina.CondicionesIVA.Gravado,//CondicionIVA
  21,//AlicuotaIVA
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeMonto.ModoRestaMonto,//OperacionMonto
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeImpuestosInternos.IIVariablePorcentual,//TipoImpuestoInterno
  10.0,//MagnitudImpuestoInterno
  HasarArgentina.ModosDeDisplay.DisplayNo,//ModoDisplay
  HasarArgentina.ModosDePrecio.ModoPrecioTotal,//ModoBaseTotal
  1,//UnidadReferencia
  "7791234500001",//CodigoProducto
  "",//CodigoInterno
  HasarArgentina.UnidadesMedida.Unidad//
)
```